# Analyzing twisted servers performance

Tags: python, performance, twisted

I have a python twistd based service which I want to do performance analysis, when I try to run yappi/cProfile for example I am getting a 95% select **cpu** time, without any callstack, does anyone have any experience analysing twisted based services? which tool can you use?